# Can't destroy crates in the level pointed by card radar

Tags: android, sky-force-reloaded

I'm back to Skyforce Reloaded after a while, and I was trying the card scanner for the first time. It points to 3rd Stage-Insane and so that's where I go to.

I can't destroy any crate in that level using different planes. After I finish the level, I get no card and the card is still there.

Is this a bug?